# Apache responding very slow on TLS handshake

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl, ssl-certificate, handshake

Having issue after installing SSL on my server. By trace

```
curl -v -o delete.txt --trace-time https://asd.com
10:45:51.449913 * Rebuilt URL to: https://asd.com/
10:45:51.450034 * Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     010:45:51.455058 *   Trying 0.0.0.0...
10:45:51.472201 * Connected to asd.com (0.0.0.0) port 443 (#0)
10:45:51.472763 * successfully set certificate verify locations:
10:45:51.472799 *   CAfile: none
CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
10:45:51.472993 * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
10:45:51.473029 } [data not shown]
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:33 --:--:--    010:46:24.872573 * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
10:46:24.872651 { [data not shown]
10:46:24.873717 * SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
```

The server sometimes respond and sometime not. It take much time to fullfill the request. Kindly help me for this.

Comment: Did you find a solution we have similar issue with our critical website where we activated HTTPS to apache and problems started, there is no easy way to go back to remove HTTPS as browsers such as firefox store https preferred state.

Comment: yes, the issue is fixed. first its better to check your error log. its states the exact problem. we have issue of maxrequest which we have increased